# Joomla 2.5 SEF URL unwanted items

Tags: url, joomla, sef

All,

I have .htaccess set up, and SEF URLs are working.  However, one category (which is actually a k2 category of items) is sowing un-wanted and unknown items:

If you see these two links, they're both to k2 item blogs, however, one contains the extra items /media-players and /share.

http://www.transcendchurch.org/multimedia/blog/sunday-synopsis
http://www.transcendchurch.org/multimedia/media-players/blog/pastors-blog/share

I'm completely mystified, as neither /media-players nor /share are legitimate names for a category or section or k2 item on the site.  Also, I've verified the configuration and menu settings for the k2 categories and joomla menu items are identical, modules assigned to each are the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work around without knowing why this happened, nor what I've done (specifically that fixed the issue).  That is, delete and rebuild the menu items, click "reorder" on the menu and the strange alias in the URL clear.  I had to relocate the k2 items from the DB - as they were all associated with an item_id that no longer existed.

I hope this helps someone.